# Vue Router - Routes with parameters

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following **router.js** with few dozens of value-x, i.e. value-one, value-2.

```
    const router = new Router({
        routes: [
            {
                path: "/plant/value-one",
                name: "value-one",
                components: {
                    default: Site
                },
                props: {
                    default: {
                        tab: 'value-one',
                        menu: 'value-one'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                path: "/plant/value-two",
                name: "value-two",
                components: {
                    default: Site
                },
                props: {
                    default: {
                        tab: 'value-two',
                        menu: 'value-two'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

I would like to turn it into something like this:

```
path: "/plant/*"
```

I tried the following:

```
    const router = new Router({
        routes: [
            {
                path: "/plant/{:name}",
                name: name,
                components: {
                    default: Site
                },
                props: {
                    default: {
                        tab: name,
                        menu: name
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

**Name** variable should also be passed to route's name as well as to **tab** and **menu** variables.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is `name`? It doesn't appear to be defined

Comment: few dozens of value-x, example: value-one, value-two

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use children routes like this:

```
{
    path: '/plant',
    component: plantComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: ':name',
            component: someComponent,
            name: 'someName'
        },

    ]
}
```

now any route after the plant/ can be defined as children of routes and i have defined a route `:name` which will be used for plant/* 
If you don't want to use children routes and just concerned with passing route parameters, use the parameter without the braces :

```
path: "/plant/:name",
```